# Did God inadvertantly create evil?

Tags: sin, good-and-evil, sovereignty

I am a Christian but I struggle with this question;

God knows everything past, present and future.  He knew us while we were still in the earth.  He picked the place, time and tree for Jesus to be crucified.

God created us, knew how we would act and what we will do in the future.  He knows we will sin against him and which of us will go to hell and which are preordained to go to Heaven...because he knows everything.  Why does he put us together that way knowing we will sin.  Why did he bother to create Satan?

I guess I would like to know why he didn't just create us with love like his.  He could have given us free will with the worst choice we would have to make is chocolate or vanilla.

Comment: I recommend the book "Who is God?" by C S Cowles to help you with this question.  Available on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Romans 9 points to some objections that Paul foresaw when speaking of the sovereign choices of God; in particular, look at verses 19-20:

"You will say to me then, 'Why does he still find fault? For who can resist his will?' **But who are you, O man, to answer back to God? Will what is molded say to its molder, 'Why have you made me like this?'**

Reading the entire context we see that there is no clear answer given, rather Paul lifts high the name of God and reminds us that finite beings cannot possibly understand all of the mysteries and ways of the LORD. I fully believe that God welcomes the humble questioning of His children, but ruminating on topics like this can lead to anger and suspicion towards God.

The Evil One has been using the same tactics since the beginning of time  ("Did God really say....?") tempting humans to doubt the word, character, wisdom, and goodness of God.

After years, literally years, of struggling with issues like this, I realized it was a fruitless struggle and simply had to ask God to change my heart, help my unbelief, and grant me a heart of trust and love for Him.

Isaiah 55:8-9 For my thoughts are not your thoughts,
    neither are your ways my ways, declares the Lord.
 For as the heavens are higher than the earth,
    so are my ways higher than your ways
    and my thoughts than your thoughts.

I don't think that anything God does can be described as inadvertent.

Isaiah 45:7 I form light and create darkness,
    I make well-being and create calamity,
    I am the Lord, who does all these things.

What an awesome God! We should tremble at His holiness and yet He became like one of us, born into a poor family and suffered at the hands of sinful man to redeem sinful man. We can trust Him!

May God bless you richly and draw you ever closer to Him.

Scripture references taken from https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+45%3A7%2C+55%3A8-9%2C+Romans+9&version=ESV